# Initialize static std::map member inside templated class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, static

Here is a code snippet from my project:

```
template<typename Second, typename First = const UINT64>
class Event : virtual public id_manager<>
{
    friend class EventHandler;
    typedef std::map<First, EventHandler> eventMap;
    static eventMap mapper;
    static eventMap StartMapping()
    {
        eventMap temp;
        return temp;
    }
public:
    Event(){}
    void operator+=(EventHandler _handler)
    {
        mapper[this->getID()] = _handler;
    }
};
// INITIALIZATION FAILED HERE:
template<typename Second, typename First = const UINT64>
Event<Second, First>::eventMap Event<Second, First>::mapper(Event<Second, First>::StartMapping());
```

Here is output error from Visual studio 2010:

> Warning   1   warning C4346: 'Event::eventMap' : dependent
>   name is not a type    c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\cppsystem\cppsystem\main.cpp    67 Error    2   error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before
>   'Event::mapper' c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\cppsystem\cppsystem\main.cpp    67 Error    3   error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\cppsystem\cppsystem\main.cpp    67 Error    4   error C1903:
>   unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping
>   compilation   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\cppsystem\cppsystem\main.cpp    67

I hope this pice of code is enough.
I can't initialize static map member using "initialization functin" for that map.
thanks alot!

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Hey thank you for that useful link... I'm reading that post from strech now! cheers my friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `typename` to tell the compiler that the eventMap is a type.

```
template<typename Second, typename First = const UINT64>
typename Event<Second, First>::eventMap Event<Second, First>::mapper(Event<Second, First>::StartMapping());
```

See [The "typename" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: thanks alot, umn ?! lol I didn't know that. I'm prety new to templates. this class template now works just fine... now have to solve other classes :D cheers!